# Big O - Is Log(A) + Log(B) == Log(AB) complexity?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o, logarithm, notation

My question stems from this: https://leetcode.com/problems/search-a-2d-matrix/

In math `Log A + Log B = Log AB`

Is this still valid for BigO notation?

Are two log searches `Log A + Log B` equal to one search of `Log AB`?

Comment: Yes, they are. You can treat the matrix as being flatten, i.e. an array of `A* B` length; binary search here has `O(log (A * B))` time complexity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, since you can manipulate the terms in Big-O notation in familiar algebraic ways, O(Log A + Log B) = O(Log AB).

When talking about two sequential searches, though, it might be more intuitive to leave it at O(Log A + Log B). You might want to simplify that to O(Log AB) if you're comparing to some other algorithm, or trying to find dominant terms.